# Problema con Asyntask-PHP

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

**Mi PHP**

```
<?php
require "dbconfig.php";

$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname) or die('Unable to connect');
if(mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
  echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name=$_POST['Query'];
$sql="SELECT name_user,SUM(cash_car) FROM usuario u 
INNER JOIN 
carro c ON u.id_user=c.id_user 
WHERE u.name_user='elias';";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($query)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $data[]=$row;
  }
    print(json_encode($data));
}else
{
  echo('Not Found ');
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Obtengo lo siguiente del archivo `PHP`

```
[{"0":"elias","name_user":"elias","1":"10","SUM(cash_car)":"10"}]
```

Y solo quisera mostrar el total de la funcion `SUM` que es **10** en este caso, ya que el otro campo (user_name) es solo para filtrar el resultado.

Pero el ejecutar la consulta mediante el `asyntask` la app deja de funcionar.

```
 private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(ganancias_totales.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pdLoading.setMessage("\tConsultando...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/total_carros/ver_total_elias.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {


                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }


                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ganancias_totales.this);
                alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las cuentas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                alertaDeError.create();
                alertaDeError.show();
            } else {
                //Existen Datos
                List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                        try {
                            preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            assert preguntaDatos != null;
                            pregrespcomment =" Cuenta" + "\n" +"> Total ganacias: "+ preguntaDatos.getString("cash_car");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        preguntas.add(pregrespcomment);

                    }

                    //crear el Adapter.
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ganancias_totales.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
                    mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);
                   // mostrarr.getAdapter().getCount();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total de cuentas: " + mostrarr.getAdapter().getCount() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ganancias_totales.this);
                    alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                    alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no existen cuentas para mostrar. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                    alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    alertaDeError.create();
                    alertaDeError.show();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Observa bien tu JSON. El mismo no tiene ninguna clave llamada `cash_car` por lo tanto esta línea del código fallará: `... preguntaDatos.getString("cash_car");` eso se resuelve dando el alias `cash_car` a la columna que hace la suma en el SELECT. O sea: `SELECT ... SUM(...) cash_car...` ahora sí tendrás una clave llamada así en tu JSON. Nótese que usar AS cash_car es opcional. No revisé todo tu código, pero debes saber que cualquier clave de JSON que quieras obtener sin que la misma exista provocará un crash en tu app. Para futuras preguntas coloca el mensaje de error del Log.

Comment: @A.Cedano afectivamente era el problema el no usar el AS, se me habia espacapado, puedes colocarla como respuesta para marcarla como correcta por favor

Comment: También ten en cuenta que si el valor que vas a obtener desde el JSON es un número, cómo sería el caso de esa columna que sería una suma, debes usar el método `getInt` del objeto JSON y no `getString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observa bien tu JSON. El mismo no tiene ninguna clave llamada `cash_car` por lo tanto esta línea del código fallará: `... preguntaDatos.getString("cash_car");`

Eso se resuelve dando el alias `cash_car` a la columna que hace la suma en el SELECT.

O sea: `SELECT ... SUM(...) cash_car...` ahora sí tendrás una clave llamada así en tu JSON.

Nótese que usar `AS cash_car` es opcional.

No revisé todo tu código, pero debes saber que cualquier clave de JSON que quieras obtener sin que la misma exista provocará un crash en tu app.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta cuando obtienes valores a partir de una clave de un objeto JSON es el tipo de dato. Si el valor es un entero debes usar `getInt` e vez de `getString`.